# How to make a read-only tinyMCE editor writetable again

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want to make some TinyMCE text editors on a page temporarily readonly.

I understand this technically possible using:

`tinymce.get('id').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);`

then we can re-enable them with:

`tinymce.get('id').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', true);`

However, I've found that using:

`tinymce.get('id').setMode('readonly');`

suits the needs of my project better when disabling as it makes the the whole textarea appear and become disabled.

My problem is that I can't then remove the `setMode('readonly')`, or find out what I should "re-set" the mode to.

I've tried:

`tinymce.get('id').setMode('readonly', 0);`

for example. But nothing seems to work.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `setMode()` API you can pass one of two `string` values to switch the mode:

- `readonly`
- `design`

For example:  `tinymce.get('content').setMode('design');`.  Here is a running example of toggling between the modes:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Gdhaab

The documentation for this can be found here:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editormode/#set